# How do I consider an element's ancestor when parsing with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: django, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 3.7, Django, and BeautifulSoup.  I am currnently looking for "span" elements in my document that contain the text "Review".  I do so like this

```
html = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=settings.SOCKET_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS).read()

my_soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

rev_elts = my_soup.findAll("span", text=re.compile("Review"))
for rev_elt in rev_elts:
    ... processing
```

but I'd like to add a wrinkle to where I don't want to consider those elements if they have a DIV ancestor with the class "child".  So for example, I don't want to consider something like this

```
    <div class="child">
        <p>
            <span class="s">Reviews</span>
        ...
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I adjust my search to take this into account?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using BeautifulSoup 4.7+, it has some improved CSS selector support. It handles many selectors up through CSS level 4 and a couple of custom ones like `:contains()`. In addition to all of that, it handles complex selectors in pseudo-classes like `:not()` which level 4 was supposed to handle, but they've recently pushed that support out to CSS level 5 selector support.

So in this example we will use the custom `:contains` selector to search for spans which contain the text `Review`. In addition, we will say we don't want it to match `div.class span`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div>
    <p><span>Review: Let's find this</span></p>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <p><span>Review: Do not want this</span></p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

spans = soup.select('span:contains(Review):not(div.child span)')
print(spans)
```

Output

```
[<span>Review: Let's find this</span>]
```

---

Depending on your case, maybe `:contains` isn't robust enough. In that case, you can still do something similar. Soup Sieve is the underlying library included with Beautiful Soup 4.7+, and you can import it directly to filter your regular expression returns:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import soupsieve as sv
import re

html = """
<div>
    <p><span>Review: Let's find this</span></p>
</div>
<div class="child">
    <p><span>Review: Do not want this</span></p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

spans = soup.find_all("span", text=re.compile("Review"))
spans = sv.filter(':not(div.child span)', spans)

print(spans)
```

Output

```
[<span>Review: Let's find this</span>]
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS selector is the way to go in this case as @facelessuser has answered. But just in case you are wondering this can be done without using css selector as well.

You can iterate over all of an element’s parents with [*.parents*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parents). You could define a [*custom filter function*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) which checks if any of the parents has a class of *"child"* and return `True` otherwise (in addition to all your other conditions).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Tag
html="""
<div class="child">
<p><span id="1">Review</span></p>
</div>
<div>
<p><span id="2">Review</span></p>
</div>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
def my_func(item):
    if isinstance(item,Tag) and item.name=='span' and 'Review' in item.text:
        for parent in item.parents:
            if parent.has_attr('class'):
                if 'child' in parent.get('class'):
                    return False
        return True
my_spans=soup.find_all(my_func)
print(my_spans)
```

Outputs:

```
[<span id="2">Review</span>]
```